# Symfony2 - Exception: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "mopa_bootstrap"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I've installed MopaBootstrapBundle using the [guidelines](http://bootstrap.mohrenweiserpartner.de/mopa/bootstrap/navbar#navbars) on the official website of the bundle.

My **config.yml**:

```
 mopa_bootstrap:
     menu': ~
```

My template:

```
{{ mopa_bootstrap_menu('mymenu') }}
```

My `src/Menu/Builder.php`:

```
namespace SsiBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;

class Builder
{
    public function createMainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
    {
        $menu = $factory->createItem('root', array(
            'navbar' => true,
        ));
        $layout = $menu->addChild('Layout', array(
            'icon' => 'home',
            'route' => 'moje',
        ));

        return $menu;
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

> FileLoaderLoadException in FileLoader.php line 130: There is no
>   extension able to load the configuration for "mopa_bootstrap" (in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SSI\app/config\config.yml). Looked for namespace
>   "mopa_bootstrap", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog",
>   "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "debug",
>   "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution" in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SSI\app/config\config.yml (which is being imported
>   from "C:\xampp\htdocs\SSI\app/config/config_dev.yml").

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the bundle in `app/AppKernel.php`.

Otherwise the bundled extension that processes configuration under the namespace `mopa_bootstrap` and registers the `mopa_bootstrap_menu` twig function is not available in your application.

Ensure the bundle is enabled in `AppKernel` as shown below and clear you cache afterwards to resolve your issue.

```
public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            // ...
            new Mopa\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\MopaBootstrapBundle(),
```